# Extjs: First panel in accordion never closed

Tags: extjs, extjs4, accordion

I looking for inserting a accordion layout in the main frame of my page in Extjs. But the first panel is never closed.

I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963814/why-does-the-first-panel-of-extjs-4-2-1-accordion-layout-never-close) but the solution wth `flex:1` does not work but with `heigth:500` works. 
Howerver I dont know the real size of my accordion panels.

Have you any other propositions?
Otherwise I will set the heigth manually, but it is ugly.

**EDIT / SOLUTION**

I finally solve my problem by using this "bug" : my accordion should be under a panel, so I put the panel as first element of my accordion. In that way the panel is never closed and all elements of the initial accordion are collapsible. It also allows me to declare my accordion without size.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a height on accordion (container of panels), otherwise it cannot determine the height of individual panels when open. Also, accordion is the layout that does not allow you to collapse all panels, however, you can have more than one open if you configure it with `multi:true`

If you do need to close all panels or if you want to contract and collapse the whole container height then don't need any layout, just wrap your panels in a container.